# Специальный класс для хранения результатов вычислений

Tags: java

Пишу код, который выполняет деление столбиком, а результат выводит графически в консоль, **например**

```
_400800|400
 400   |----
 ---   |1002
   _800
    800
    ---
      0
```

У меня есть метод, который делает вычисления и сразу формирует строку результата, которую выводит в консоль.

**Необходимо** переделать этот метод по принципу единственной ответственности. Например, создать класс который берет два числа и делит их, затем сохраняет в специальный класс для хранения результатов, а класс для отображения результата берет эти результаты и формирует строку для вывода.
**Как все это организовать?** Я новичок, поэтому звучит легко, а сделать не получается.Может направите меня или дадите ссылку где можно изучить похожий принцип?

Comment: откуда взялась такая странная задача?

Comment: Занимаюсь с ментором, вот он мне и дал такую

Comment: смотрел мой вариант? (проглядел с языком, извини) класс для консольного вывода может еще написать?

Comment: Если не сложно, то был бы рад!

Comment: что думаешь об IEnumerable? понимаешь прием?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

возьми мою задумку, должно стать легче: (забыл добавить: код на C#, но механика та же)

```
class Class1
{
    public readonly Class1 son;
    public readonly string num1;
    public readonly string num2;
    public readonly string res;
    public readonly int space;
    public Class1(int dividend, int divider, int space = 1)
    {
        if (divider < 1) throw new ArgumentException();

        num1 = dividend.ToString();
        this.space = space;
        if (divider > dividend) //если попадаем внутрь - конец деления, делаем заглушку
        {
            //this.space = num1.Length - 1 + space;
            num2 = "";
            return;
        }
        int res = dividend / divider;
        this.res = res.ToString();
        int i = 0; //сдвиг влево
        while (res > 9)
        {
            res = res / 10;
            i++;
        }
        int delta = res * divider; //число вычитаемое из делимого
        num2 = delta.ToString();


        if (i >= 0) //остаток все еще больше делителя
        {
            int newDividend = dividend - delta * MyPow(10, i);
            int spaceDelta = num1.Length - newDividend.ToString().Length;
            son = new Class1(newDividend, divider, space + spaceDelta);
        }


    }

    static int MyPow(int x, int y)
    {
        if (y == 0) return 1;
        if (y < 1) throw new ArgumentException();

        int res = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
        {
            res *= x;
        }
        return res;
    }

    public int Num2RightSpace()
    {
        return num1.Length - num2.Length;
    }
}
```

класс для генерации строкового представления:

- способ 1: все в кучу, немного непонятно
- способ 2: добавил C# магии

---

```
class Class2
{
    public static string Class1ToString(Class1 c1)
    {
        if (c1.son != null)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(' ', c1.space - 1).Append('_').Append(c1.num1) //число в первой строчке
                .Append('|').Append(c1.num2).Append('\n') //заголовок первой строчки
                .Append(' ', c1.space).Append(c1.num2).Append(' ', c1.Num2RightSpace()) //число второй строки
                .Append('|').Append('-', c1.num2.Length).Append('\n') //разделитель заголовка
                .Append(' ', c1.space).Append('-', c1.num2.Length).Append(' ', c1.Num2RightSpace()) //разделитель
                .Append('|').Append(c1.res).Append('\n'); //результат деления


            while (c1.son != null)
            {
                c1 = c1.son;
                if (c1.num2 != "")
                    sb.Append(' ', c1.space - 1).Append('_').Append(c1.num1).Append('\n')
                        .Append(' ', c1.space).Append(c1.num2).Append(' ', c1.Num2RightSpace()).Append('\n')
                        .Append(' ', c1.space).Append('-', c1.num2.Length).Append(' ', c1.Num2RightSpace()).Append('\n');
                else
                    sb.Append(' ', c1.space).Append(c1.num1).Append('\n');
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        else throw new NotSupportedException();

    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> Class1ToStringV2(Class1 c1)
    {
        var e = GetS(c1).GetEnumerator();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        e.MoveNext();
        sb.Append(e.Current).Append('|').Append(c1.num2);
        yield return sb.ToString();
        sb.Clear();

        e.MoveNext();
        sb.Append(e.Current).Append('|').Append('-', c1.num2.Length);
        yield return sb.ToString();
        sb.Clear();

        e.MoveNext();
        sb.Append(e.Current).Append('|').Append(c1.res);
        yield return sb.ToString();
        sb.Clear();

        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return e.Current;
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> GetS(Class1 c1)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (c1.num2 != "")
        {
            sb.Append(' ', c1.space - 1).Append('_').Append(c1.num1);
            yield return sb.ToString();
            sb.Clear();
            sb.Append(' ', c1.space).Append(c1.num2).Append(' ', c1.Num2RightSpace());
            yield return sb.ToString();
            sb.Clear();
            sb.Append(' ', c1.space).Append('-', c1.num2.Length).Append(' ', c1.Num2RightSpace());
            yield return sb.ToString();
            sb.Clear();

            c1 = c1.son;
        }
        sb.Append(' ', c1.space).Append(c1.num1);
        yield return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

инициализируешь его для своего примера:

```
var c = new Class1(987654321, 50);

Console.WriteLine(Class2.Class1ToString(c));//способ 1

foreach (var s in Class2.Class1ToStringV2(c)) //способ 2
{
     Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

### вот что получается:

[image: вывод консоли]

Comment: если хочешь создать КЛ1 со случаем когда делитель больше делимого - у тебя ничего хорошего не выйдет такое состояние используется как заглушка в конце очереди

Comment: спасибо, написал свой класс используя вашу идею!